# Accessing a database created with flask-sqlalchemy from a separate flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
+-- myproject
   ¦
   +-- api
   ¦   +-- tests
   ¦   +-- app
   ¦   +-- blueprint_1
   ¦   +-- blueprint_2
   ¦
   +-- data_collector
       +-- tests
       +-- app
       +-- scraper
```

My json api project using Flask and flask-sqlalchemy is structured as the above. The data_collector app I plan to setup to run automatically every hour to scrape the latest hourly data published on a webpage, then populate a database with this data. The api app I want to use to return json according to queries specified in the blueprints.

So far I have been able to populate an sqlite database using the data_collector app but I can only query the database from within this app, not the api app. I have been reading the [flask-sqlalchemy docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  and reading up elsewhere.  For starters, is there a better way I should be structuring my project?

My data_collector app instantiates the database as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I am not able to access the db or app object from outside this file. So I cannot put my models in a separate file since my models have db.Models as the base class. From the docs I think I need to have the following instead of the above:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

I have tried this in both my apps, but still get the same error: 'Cannot import app from app' or 'Cannot import db from app'. I am not sure my app within the api directory will need access to app from data_collector since it is independent, but I am still not able to access the sqlite database that I created. How can I access the database.db file created using data_collector from a separate app (I have tried as best I can to follow info in the docs and elsewhere on the internet)?

Comment: Create a separate package for your model that also has the `db` singleton. Import from said module in both your apps and `db.init_app(app)`. I guess you could also hold the required DB configuration in the model package and extend your app configuration with that.

Comment: The official documentation actually describes what you have to do quite well: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/#factories-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind `db` to `app` manually.

```py
# db.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

def init_app(app):
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    app.db = db
```

```py
# __init__.py
from flask import Flask
from . import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Most flask applications will instantiate a `db` and `app` as a global variable and import them in other files. I don't think we should import static variables (except for constants). I think a more pythonic way is to import modules.